# Display string async with delay

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, task

I am trying to display a string in a web page with delay and the following is what I tried but the page does not show until the delay is expired.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Print().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private async Task Print()
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        pr.InnerText = "this is a test...";
    });
}
```

Comment: How would delaying something server-side (on a usually buffered output) result in a delayed certain text on a page? Better use a client-side JS timer to show the previously hidden text after a delay. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/o90fcdu5/).

Comment: Yes but what if I want to display data from the database while reading?

Comment: In this case, use AJAX.

Comment: You click a button and page travels to server. Code behind runs. If you block or await delay? Then page is STILL stuck up on the server side until such time all server side code is done. ONLY THEN does the page make the trip back down to the browser side. If have a thread or code continue to run after the web page makes trip to browser? Then that code is  modifying a copy of the web page server side - but it not going to update or make a trip back down to the browser side copy. Thus ajax or a js timer + web call is required. You can also consider a update panel + timer to update a panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend removing this delay from the backend and on the front end use javascript to to asynchronously call the back end for the string.  You can use setTimeout and ajax post to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is synchronous code, the "correct" way is simply:

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    pr.InnerText = "this is a test...";
}
```

However, this won't solve your issue. You added a delay on the server-side code generation, so all you've succeeded is to wait longer until everything appears on the client-side. You should look into AJAX calls to load your data asynchronously on the client side, and send the whole page framework as soon as possible from the server side.

Edit: alternatively, use a modern framework like Blazor, where something like this would work. WebForms has been dead for over 10 years.

Comment: In the release blog posts for .NET 5 I read somewhere that Microsoft officially recommends that instead of Web Forms, developers should use Blazor in .NET 5.